# How to get the digest of image with specific tag by using Docker repository API from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, image, api, repository, hub

I am going to get the digest of image with specific tag on Docker Hub.
There are 3 images with different tags on docker Hub.
Could you provide the curl & GET command example for getting the image digest with specific tag on Docker Hub?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:
[Can I get an image digest without downloading the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375421/can-i-get-an-image-digest-without-downloading-the-image)

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' dockerHubRepo/dockerImageName:tag
```

Or (cf the above link) :

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Basic ${username_password_base64}" \
     'https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:dockerHubRepo/dockerImageName:tag:pull'
```