# Check for new docker image version without pull

Tags: docker

I know Watchtower (https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower), but would like to understand if there is a way that I check for docker image updates without pull (downloading it)

I seems that if I ie. use docker pull pihole:latest it download the image, no matter if it the newest or already on my device.

I would like to get the digest or image id from the docker hub, so I can compare it with my local image id

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39375421/1220269

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get an image digest without downloading the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375421/can-i-get-an-image-digest-without-downloading-the-image)